# I want to deserialize a json object in angular, using the typescript-json-serializer library

Tags: angular, typescript, json-deserialization

I created a class to map a json object I am getting from a java backend service, the problem is one of the key from the json object is 'function' and I can not use that as a field name in the angular class.

I used the typescript-json-serializer library to help map the field but it is still returning undefined

```
import {JsonObject, JsonProperty} from "typescript-json-serializer";

@JsonObject()
export class Process{
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public createdBy: string,
    @JsonProperty("function") public _function: string
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: As long as I know, there is no limitation to use `function` as field name, and you don't need `typescript-json-serializer` too. You can see this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqrcb2?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: This worked perfectly, had to move the function from the constructor for it to work. Thank you